# Finding WPS pin without accessing router

Tags: wi-fi

So my android phone is not rooted. I have username and password of my friends WPS enabled wifi. So now if I want to view it's WPS pin remotely is it possible without root?
(EDUCATIONAL PURPOSE)

Comment: The WPS PIN technology is fundamentally broken and should be disabled in any Wifi. Anyway a simple Google search would have pointed to dozens of posts describing how to hack WPS PIN for example: https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-wi-fi-breaking-wps-pin-get-password-with-bully-0158819/

Comment: i wonder this is android question

Comment: maybe related to your question if you don't care about WPS Pin https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218514