# recover WiFi password file Android Pie

Tags: wi-fi, 9.0-pie, magisk

I know that Android (at least Pie) uses a file WifiConfigStore.xml to store WiFi access points and passwords. It is located in /data/misc/wifi/.

I saved it before wipe and reinstall everything. The idea was to copy it back to this location. While the phone is on/powered it seems not to uses the information from this new file. But after reboot it is gone and overwritten.

So my question: is there a special trick? Or is this not the proper location? Is there some backup file stored somewhere else?

(I have a rooted LineageOS 16 device with Magisk. I even tried to change the file in TWRP with not better result.)

Edit: Found that this file is also located in
/data/misc_ce/0/wifi, 
/sbin/.magisk/mirror/data/misc/wifi and 
/sbin/.magisk/mirror/data/misc_ce/wifi

And there are also files 
WifiConfigStore.xml.encrypted-checksum. From naming it sounds like there it is including a checksum to avoid errors in xml? 
This file I have not saved. Am I lost now? Can I delete this and it will be created than?

What is function of this misc_ce folders?

Thanks!

Comment: /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: This has been used in older versions - it is not active used anymore... I can see all the data in this (saved) WifiConfigStore.xml.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the magisk folder is just a link. Not sure about the misc_ce folder.
I copied WifiConfigStore.xml, changed properties and owners and renamed the checksum file. After reboot the checksum was recreated and the xml gets valid...

Comment: I can confirm it works. So I've written a tool to convert old `wpa_supplicant.conf` to `WifiConfigStore.xml` if anyone is interested: https://github.com/mnalis/android-wifi-upgrade